# STL File Exporting with Incorrect Origin Point

Tags: objects, export, transforms, origin, stl

I'm trying to set a new origin of rotation of a STL file using Blender. I've imported the STL file into Blender and changed the origin (using Origin to 3D Cursor), which allows me to rotate the object around my preferred point. When I try to export the object to a STL file again, the origin reverts back to the original point prior to me changing it.

Does anyone know why this would be happening?

Answer (score 1):

I am not too sure whether you can change the origin of objects in STL files. However, from my experiment, I found that Blender exports all STL objects with an origin to Geometry - Bounded Box. If you are using the object to 3D print. I reccommend the following steps

1. Put the origin where you want to place in the Object in Blender.
2. Set the Object's origin to 0,0,0
3. Scale down the model to the exact dimensions you want to 3D print
4. In object mode, set origin to Geometry. A box on the bottom right will come out toggle it to Bounded Box.
5. Record the x and y coordinates
6. Export your Object, Remember to set scale to 1000
7. Open your STL file in slicer of your preference
8. Set the X & Y Coordinates as per Step 5